# Google Guice: expose a named object but keep it available within the module without a name

Tags: guice

My application is built using Guice and MyBatis.
Different database connections are represented using javax.sql.DataSource.
All classes that need access to a DataSource are declared within the same Guice PrivateModule that provides this DataSource as well.
However, these modules grow over time and are harder to manage. In addition, I would like to be able to tie different DAO and their related classes into a separate Guice module and provide that module with a data source so the above module is better encapsulated and reusable with different data sources.

Technically speaking I would like to be able to write something like:

```
public class MyDataSourceModule extends PrivateModule {

   @Override
   protected void configure() {}

   @Exposed
   @Named("systemDataSource")
   @Singleton
   @Provides
   DataSource provideDataSource() {
       return ...;
   }
}
```

such that the DataSource will be still available without a name within the module but only with the name outside the module. Annotations can be changed as needed. Is that possible and how?

Comment: Have you tried your own code sample? At first glance, I don’t see any reason it wouldn’t work.

Comment: Have you tried my code sample or just glanced at it? :-)
Once you @Named something it's difficult to access it just by the type without the name

Comment: No, I haven’t had a chance to run it yet. Do you have some constraint that requires you to use an `@Provides` method, or could you use a solution that uses EDSL bindings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is possible by creating two different bindings in the same module.

(Side note: if you're not familiar with BindingAnnotations, you can find out more [here](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations). In my examples, I will be using `@UsingSystemDataSource` as the binding annotation.)

Using EDSL in the `configure()` method:

```
protected void configure() {
    // binding for private use
    bind(DataSource.class).to(SystemDataSourceImpl.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);

    // binding for public use
    bind(DataSource.class).annotatedWith(@UsingSystemDataSource.class).to(DataSource.class);
    expose(DataSource.class).annotatedWith(@UsingSystemDataSource.class);
}
```

Now, if you need to do this without using EDSL, then your private module `@Provides` methods would look like this:

```
@Provides
@Exposed
@UsingSystemDataSource
DataSource provideDataSourcePublicly(DataSource privatelyBoundDatasource) {
    return privatelyBoundDatasource;
}

@Provides
@Singleton
DataSource provideDataSource() {
    return ...;
}
```

---

**Why does this even work?**

This actually creates two different bindings—one linking `DataSource` to `SystemDataSource` and another linking `@UsingSystemDataSource DataSource` to `DataSource`.  Using the `expose()` method or `@Exposed`, the private module exposes *only* the annotated version of the binding. (I couldn't find a source that explicitly states that it works for this use case, so I tested it myself.)

Comment: This is nice but why did you create the @UsingSystemDataSource BindingAnnotations instead of using @Named?

Comment: It’s a “best practice”. Guice recommends using purpose-built annotations because the compiler can check them. (The compiler cannot see if the string in `@Named` is correct.)

Comment: Well but then the runtime will quite quickly on startup. I like the concept of Named and the fact that it's build in. But doesn't changes the answer much.